# Ubuntu 14.04.02 Live USB boots to black sceen

Tags: 14.04, hp

I have downloaded 14.04.02 image : ubuntu-14.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso but when I make a bootable USB out of it and install it my Laptop screen Goes black after I select "Install Ubuntu" option.
I have no problem in creating and installing 12.04.02 image : ubuntu-12.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso image.
I am having HP ELiteBook 8470P with Intel Core I5.
I am using Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.5.9.exe to create the USB disk on Windows.
Any Idea what wrong I am doing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: I checked the post , but after I get the Menu options for using, installing ,checking CD,etc even if I select check disk, it becomes all black.Is it some problem with my graphics driver?

Comment: Also there is some related pOst showing some problem ni the HP Systems  - http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2252551 .Has any one been able to install Ubuntu 14.04 successfully on HP 8470P??

Comment: So, how about the `nomodset` option?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen a case of Ubuntu 14.04.2 on VirtualBox, that boots and automatically switches to tty3, which is empty.

You can test, if it's the same problem by waiting 20-40 seconds and press ALT+F1, to switch to tty1. If you see login prompt there, it's the same problem. If not, it's something else.

Comment: in my case I am stuck at the step of installation, Booting itself is far away !

Comment: Sorry, I missed one thing: choose "boot as live cd" option (I don't remember its exact name now). Then it will try to boot. Then try ALT+F1.

Comment: If it doesn't react to ALT+F1 or CTRL+ALT+F1, then it's compatibility problem, most probably with graphics card or pen drive, or it's caused by broken image, or broken pen drive itself.