# Compatible kernel to build for Ubuntu 12.04.LTS

Tags: 12.04, kernel

I have Ubuntu 12.04.02 with kernel 3.13.

I wanted to upgrade the kernel to 3.18 using the same Ubuntu 12.04.02.

Is there a possibility to breaking something. I want to debug a driver by doing so?

please suggest , I am newbie. 
Regards

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to install unsupported kernels. Some drivers may not build, or other issues may occur. There must be a really good reason to upgrade the kernel.

A better solution is to upgrade distribution to 14.04 LTS.

You can have a supported 3.13, 3.16 or 3.19 kernel in 14.04.

But you can install any kernel image from [Ubuntu mainline kernel PPA](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/) at your own risk.

But if you are new to Ubuntu I highly **NOT** recommend doing it.

Comment: A better solution is to upgrade distribution to 14.04 LTS.>>>This is I think not supported on some Model.I have installed 14.0.02 Ubuntu on HP 8470p but alas , after the installation it all goes black,This model name is also not here in the list of HP  Supported models for Ubuntu 14.04 --> http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/make/HP/ and when I posted this , it was marked as Duplicate : ( --> http://askubuntu.com/questions/635433/ubuntu-14-04-02-live-usb-boots-to-black-sceen !!

Comment: @softy That certification does not mean much. If you had trouble with 14.04, then most likely you have more trouble with unsupported kernels. But black screen issues can be solved in most cases.